# Using nodes to undo a move on Board in C++!

Tags: c++

For this project my teacher gave me code which is a text version of the 1024/2048 game. When the game is started the user starts with two number on the board (either a 2 or a 4). And then eveytime you move a new number pops up, if two adjacent numbers are of the same value they add together to form the sum of those numbers. I have to make a node so I can undo the each move that is made. I have successfully been able to pass each move into the node. But when I call my goBack function to undo the move, it just displays the same board. Here is the code, can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>   // used for setting output field size using setw
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;


typedef struct Node {

    int *board;// keep track of board
    int *score; // keep track of score
    int *boardSize; // keep track of the board size
    struct Node* pNext; // node pointer
}Node;

Node* goBack(Node* pHead) {
    if (pHead != NULL) {
        // create a temp pointer to hold the original head
        Node* temp = pHead;
        // pHead is pointing to next one
        pHead = pHead->pNext;
        // free the orinal head's memory!!
        delete temp;

    }

    return pHead;
}

Node* addNode(Node* pHead,  int board[], int boardSize, int score ) {
    // create a new node, and set the letter and count
    Node* newNodePtr = new Node();

    newNodePtr->board = board;
    newNodePtr->boardSize = &boardSize;
    newNodePtr->score = &score;


    // insert it at the beginning (new node's next is set to original head)
    newNodePtr->pNext = pHead;
    cout<<"here";
    // return the new node's point (which will be the new head)
    return newNodePtr;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// Display ID info
void displayIDInfo()
{
    cout << "Dale Reed          \n";
    cout << "UIC CS 141, Spring 2014           \n";
    cout << "Welcome to 1024 and More. \n";
    cout << "This program is based off of Gabriele Cirulli's game online at \n";
    cout << "    bit.ly/great2048 \n";
    cout << " \n";
}//end displayIDInfo()


//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// Display Instructions
void displayInstructions()
{
    cout << "For each move enter a direction as a letter key, as follows: \n"
    << "    W    \n"
    << "  A S D  \n"
    << "where A=left,W=up, D=right and S=down. \n"
    << "  \n"
    << "After a move, when two identical valued tiles come together they    \n"
    << "join to become a new single tile with the value of the sum of the   \n"
    << "two originals. This value gets added to the score.  On each move    \n"
    << "one new randomly chosen value of 2 or 4 is placed in a random open  \n"
    << "square.  User input of x exits the game.                            \n"
    << "  \n";
}//end displayInstructions()


//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// Place a randomly selected 2 or 4 into a random open square on
// the board.
void placeRandomPiece( int board[], int boardSize)
{
    // Randomly choose a piece to be placed (2 or 4)
    int pieceToPlace = 2;
    if( rand()%2 == 1) {
        pieceToPlace = 4;
    }

    // Find an unoccupied square that currently has a 0
    int index;
    do {
        index = rand() % (boardSize*boardSize);
    }while( board[ index] != 0);

    // board at position index is blank, so place piece there
    board[ index] = pieceToPlace;
}//end placeRandomPiece()


//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// Prompt for and get board size, dynamically allocate space for the
// board, initialize the board and set the max tile value that
// corresponds to the board size.
void getSizeAndSetBoard( int * &board,          // board that is dynamically allocated
                        int * &previousBoard,  // space for copy of board
                        int &boardSize,        // size of the board, entered by user
                        int &maxTileValue)     // max tile value, depending on board size
{
    // Prompt for board size and set corresponding game end value
    //    cout << "Enter the size board you want, between 4 and 12: ";
    //    cin >> boardSize;

    // Allocate space for the 2-d board (and board copy), stored as a 1-d array
    board = new int[ boardSize * boardSize];  // e.g. a board of size 4 will have 4x4=16 elements
    previousBoard = new int[ boardSize * boardSize];

    // Initialize board to all 0's
    for( int row=0; row<boardSize; row++) {
        for( int col=0; col<boardSize; col++ ) {
            board[ row*boardSize + col] = 0;
        }
    }

    // Calculate and display game ending value
    for( int i=4; i<boardSize; i++) {
        maxTileValue = maxTileValue * 2;   // double for each additional board dimension > 4
    }
    cout << "Game ends when you reach " << maxTileValue << "." << endl;

    // Set two random pieces to start game
    placeRandomPiece( board, boardSize);
    placeRandomPiece( board, boardSize);

}//end getSizeAndSetBoard()


//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// Display the Board
void displayBoard( int *board, int boardSize, int score)
{
    // Set display width value depending on boardSize (and corresponding max value)
    int displayWidth;
    switch( boardSize) {
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
        case 7: displayWidth = 5; break;  // up to   8,192
        case 8:
        case 9:
        case 10: displayWidth = 6; break; // up to  65,536
        case 11:
        case 12: displayWidth = 7; break; // up to 262,144
        default:
            // Sanity check, should never get here
            cout << "Invalid boardSize of " << boardSize
            << ". Exiting program..\n" << endl;
            exit( -1);
            break;
    }

    cout << "\n"
    <<"Score: " << score << endl;
    for( int row=0; row<boardSize; row++) {
        cout << "   ";
        for( int col=0; col<boardSize; col++ ) {
            int current = row*boardSize + col;  // 1-d index corresponding to row & col
            cout << setw( 6);    // set output field size to 6 (Requires #include <iomanip> )
            // display '.' if board value is 0
            if( board[ current] == 0) {
                cout << '.';
            }
            else {
                cout << board[ current];
            }
        }
        cout << "\n\n";
    }
}//end displayBoard()


//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// Make a copy of the board.  This is used after an attempted move
// to see if the board actually changed.
void copyBoard(
               int previousBoard[], // destination for board copy
               int board[],         // board from which copy will be made
               int boardSize)       // size of the board
{
    for( int row=0; row<boardSize; row++) {
        for( int col=0; col<boardSize; col++ ) {
            int current = row*boardSize + col;  // 1-d index corresponding to row & col
            previousBoard[ current] = board[ current];
        }
    }
}//end copyBoard()


//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// See if board changed this turn. If not, no additional piece
// is randomly added and move number does not increment in main().
// Returns true if boards are different, false otherwise.
bool boardChangedThisTurn( int previousBoard[], int board[], int boardSize)
{
    // Compare element by element.  If one is found that is different
    // then return true, as board was changed.
    for( int row=0; row<boardSize; row++) {
        for( int col=0; col<boardSize; col++ ) {
            int current = row*boardSize + col;  // 1-d index corresponding to row & col
            if( previousBoard[ current] != board[ current]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;  // No board difference was found
}


// While the 4 functions below (slideLeft(), slideRight(), slideUp(), slideDown() ) could
// be all combined into a single function, that single function would be difficult to
// understand, so these 4 functions were left separate.


//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// Slide all tiles left, combining matching values, updating the score
void slideLeft( int board[], int boardSize, int &score)
{

    // handle each row separately
    for( int row=0; row<boardSize; row++) {
        // set index limit for this row to be index of left-most tile on this row
        int limit = row * boardSize;

        // Start from the second column and process each element from left to right
        for( int col=1; col<boardSize; col++) {

            // get 1-d array index based on row and col
            int current = row * boardSize + col;

            // slide current piece over as far left as possible
            while( board[ current-1] == 0 && current > limit) {
                board[ current-1] = board[ current];
                board[ current] = 0;
                current--;
            }

            // Combine it with left neighbor if values are the same and non zero.
            // The additional check for (current > limit) ensures a tile can be combined
            // at most once on a move, since limit is moved right every time a combination is made.
            // This ensures a row of:  2 2 4 4   ends up correctly as:  4 8 0 0   and not:  8 4 0 0
            if( (board[ current-1] == board[ current]) && (board[ current] != 0) && (current > limit)) {
                board[ current-1] = board[ current-1] + board[ current];
                board[ current] = 0;
                limit = current;           // Reset row index limit, to prevent combining a piece more than once
                score += board[ current-1];  // Update score

            }

        }//end for( int col...
    }//end for( int row...


}//end slideLeft()


//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// Slide all tiles right, combining matching values, updating the score
void slideRight( int board[], int boardSize, int &score)
{

    // handle each row separately
    for( int row=0; row<boardSize; row++) {
        // set index limit for this row to be index of right-most tile on this row
        int limit = row * boardSize + boardSize - 1;

        // Start from the second-to-last column and process each element from right to left
        for( int col=boardSize - 1; col>=0; col--) {

            // get 1-d array index based on row and col
            int current = row * boardSize + col;

            // slide current piece over as far right as possible
            while( board[ current+1] == 0 && current < limit) {
                board[ current+1] = board[ current];
                board[ current] = 0;
                current++;
            }

            // Combine it with right neighbor if values are the same and non zero.
            // The additional check for (current < limit) ensures a tile can be combined
            // at most once on a move, since limit is moved left every time a combination is made.
            // This ensures a row of:  4 4 2 2   ends up correctly as:  0 0 8 4   and not:  0 0 4 8
            if( (board[ current+1] == board[ current]) && (board[ current] != 0) && (current < limit)) {
                board[ current+1] = board[ current+1] + board[ current];
                board[ current] = 0;
                limit = current;           // Reset row index limit, to prevent combining a piece more than once
                score += board[ current+1];  // Update score

            }

        }//end for( int col...
    }//end for( int row...


}//end slideRight()


//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// Slide all tiles up, combining matching values, updating the score
void slideUp( int board[], int boardSize, int &score)
{

    // handle each column separately
    for( int col=0; col<boardSize; col++) {
        // set index limit for this column to be index of top-most tile on this row
        int limit = col;

        // Start from the second row and process each element from top to bottom
        for( int row=1; row<boardSize; row++) {

            // get 1-d array index based on row and col
            int current = row * boardSize + col;

            // slide current piece up as far as possible
            while( board[ current-boardSize] == 0 && current > limit) {
                board[ current-boardSize] = board[ current];
                board[ current] = 0;
                current = current - boardSize;
            }

            // Combine it with upper neighbor if values are the same and non zero.
            // The additional check for (current > limit) ensures a tile can be combined
            // at most once on a move, since limit is moved down every time a combination is made.
            if( (board[ current-boardSize] == board[ current]) && (board[ current] != 0) && (current > limit)) {
                board[ current-boardSize] = board[ current-boardSize] + board[ current];
                board[ current] = 0;
                limit = current;           // Reset row index limit, to prevent combining a piece more than once
                score += board[ current-boardSize];  // Update score

            }

        }//end for( int col...
    }//end for( int row...


}//end slideUp()


//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// Slide all tiles down, combining matching values, updating the score
void slideDown( int board[], int boardSize, int &score)
{

    // handle each column separately
    for( int col=0; col<boardSize; col++) {
        // set index limit for this column to be index of bottom-most tile on this row
        int limit = (boardSize - 1) * boardSize + col;

        // Start from the next to last row and process each element from bottom to top
        for( int row=boardSize-1; row>=0; row--) {

            // get 1-d array index based on row and col
            int current = row * boardSize + col;

            // slide current piece down as far as possible
            while( board[ current+boardSize] == 0 && current < limit) {
                board[ current+boardSize] = board[ current];
                board[ current] = 0;
                current = current + boardSize;
            }

            // Combine it with lower neighbor if values are the same and non zero.
            // The additional check for (current < limit) ensures a tile can be combined
            // at most once on a move, since limit is moved up every time a combination is made.
            if( (board[ current+boardSize] == board[ current]) && (board[ current] != 0) && (current < limit)) {
                board[ current+boardSize] = board[ current+boardSize] + board[ current];
                board[ current] = 0;
                limit = current;           // Reset row index limit, to prevent combining a piece more than once
                score += board[ current+boardSize];  // Update score

            }

        }//end for( int col...
    }//end for( int row...


}//end slideDown()


//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// Return true if we're not done, false if we *are* done
//    Game is done if board is full and no more valid moves can be made
//    or if a tile with maxTileValue has been created.
bool notDone( int board[],      // current board
             int boardSize,    // size of one side of board
             int maxTileValue) // max tile value for this size board
{

    // See if the maxTileValue is found anywhere on the board.
    // If so, game is over.
    for( int i=0; i<boardSize*boardSize; i++) {
        if( board[ i] == maxTileValue) {
            cout << "Congratulations!  You made it to " << maxTileValue << " !!!" << endl;
            return false;  // there are open squares, so we are not done yet
        }
    }

    // See if there are any open squares.  If so return true since we aren't done
    for( int i=0; i<boardSize*boardSize; i++) {
        if( board[ i] == 0) {
            return true;  // there are open squares, so we are not done yet
        }
    }

    // All squares are full.
    // To check if board is done, make a copy of board, then slide left
    // and slide down.  If resulting board is same as original, we are done
    // with game since there are no moves to be made.
    int *boardCopy = new int[ boardSize * boardSize];
    copyBoard( boardCopy, board, boardSize);
    int tempScore = 0;   // used as a placeHolder only for function calls below
    slideLeft( boardCopy, boardSize, tempScore);
    slideDown( boardCopy, boardSize, tempScore);

    // Compare each square of boards.  If any is different, a move is possible
    for( int i=0; i<boardSize*boardSize; i++) {
        if( boardCopy[ i] != board[ i]) {
            return true;  // Game is not done
        }
    }

    cout << "\n"
    << "No more available moves.  Game is over.\n"
    << "\n";
    return false;  // Game is done since all squares are full and there are no moves
}//end notDone()


//--------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    Node *pHead = NULL;
    int score = 0;
    int boardSize = 4;        // user will enter this value.  Set default to 4
    int *board;               // space will be dynamically allocated depending on user selected size
    int *previousBoard;       // store copy of board, used to see if a move changed the board
    int maxTileValue = 1024;  // 1024 for 4x4 board, 2048 for 5x5, 4096 for 6x6, etc.
    char userInput = ' ';     // handles user input
    int move = 1;             // user move counter

    // Display ID info and instructions
    displayIDInfo();
    displayInstructions();

    // get the board size, create and initialize the board, and set the max tile value
    getSizeAndSetBoard( board, previousBoard, boardSize, maxTileValue);

    // Main loop to display board, prompt for and handle move and check for win
    do {
        // Display the board
        displayBoard( board, boardSize, score);

        // Copy board.  After attempting a move this is used to verify that the board
        // changed, which allows randomly placing an additional piece on board and
        // updating the move number.
        copyBoard( previousBoard, board, boardSize);  // copy from board into previousBoard

        // Prompt for and handle user input
        cout << move << ". Your move: ";
        cin >> userInput;
        switch (userInput) {
            case 'x':
                cout << "Thanks for playing. Exiting program...";
                exit( 0);
                break;
            case 'r':
                cout << "\n"
                << "Resetting board \n"
                << "\n";
                getSizeAndSetBoard( board, previousBoard, boardSize, maxTileValue);
                score = 0;
                move = 1;
                continue;  // go back up to main loop and restart game
                break;
            case 'a':
                slideLeft( board, boardSize, score);  // Slide left
                pHead = addNode(pHead, board, boardSize, score);
                break;
            case 's':
                slideDown( board, boardSize, score);  // Slide down
                pHead = addNode(pHead, board, boardSize, score);
                break;
            case 'd':
                slideRight( board, boardSize, score); // Slide right
                pHead = addNode(pHead, board, boardSize, score);
                break;
            case 'w':
                slideUp( board, boardSize, score);    // Slide up
                pHead = addNode(pHead, board, boardSize, score);
                break;
            case'u':
                pHead = goBack(pHead);// go back
                break;
            case 'p':
                // Place a piece on the board
                int index;  // 1-d array index location to place piece
                int value;  // value to be placed
                cin >> index >> value;
                board[ index] = value;
                continue;  // Do not increment move number or place random piece
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Invalid input, please retry.";
                continue;
                break;
        }//end switch( userInput)

        // If the move resulted in pieces changing position, then it was a valid move
        // so place a new random piece (2 or 4) in a random open square and update move number.
        if( boardChangedThisTurn( previousBoard, board, boardSize)) {
            // Place a random piece on board
            placeRandomPiece( board, boardSize);

            // Update move number after a valid move
            move++;
        }

        // clear the screen, which is system("clear") on UNIX and system("cls") on Windows
        //system("clear");
        system("cls");

    }while( notDone( board, boardSize, maxTileValue));

    // Display final board
    displayBoard( board, boardSize, score);

    cout << "Exiting program...\n\n";
    return 0;
}//end main()
```

Comment: In the future, please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That is just way to much code to read!

Answer (score 2):

```
newNodePtr->board = board;
```

You do not copy the board here. Instead, you copy a pointer to the board. So all your 'nodes' store pointer to the very same board (which is the current state of the game).

You need to copy the contents of the board by allocating and copying the whole array.

Comment: Any idea how I can do this? Would memccpy() help?

Comment: Yes, `memcpy` can be used for that. Or you can simply copy elements with a loop.

Comment: pTemp->board = memcpy(board, &boardSize, sizeof(int));

Comment: would it be something like this?

Comment: No. You have to allocate the memory first (e.g. using new). And then you should use memcpy properly (read its documentation and find out what it does and how to use it).